# How can I handle different raw types by only one class(covariance and contravariance)

Tags: scala

I have a question regarding type inference in Scala. I have a super type `AuthInfo` and certain sub types like `PasswordInfo` or `OAuth1Info`. To each sub type I have a DAO which can persist this specific type. Now I have a service that should accept all of my sub types and delegate actions for a specific sub type to its specific DAO.

---

The super type `AuthInfo`:

```
trait AuthInfo
```

Certain sub types of `AuthInfo`:

```
class PasswordInfo extends AuthInfo

class OAuth1Info extends AuthInfo
```

The DAO which should only handle sub types of `AuthInfo`:

```
trait AuthInfoDAO[T <: AuthInfo] {

  val classTag: ClassTag[T]

  def save(loginInfo: LoginInfo, authInfo: T): Future[T]

  def find(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Option[T]]
}
```

The service which should only handle sub types of `AuthInfo`:

```
trait AuthInfoService {

  def save[T <: AuthInfo](loginInfo: LoginInfo, authInfo: T): Future[T]

  def retrieve[T <: AuthInfo](loginInfo: LoginInfo)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Future[Option[T]]
}
```

Now I have implementations of the DAOs:

```
class PasswordInfoDAO(implicit val classTag: ClassTag[PasswordInfo]) extends AuthInfoDAO[PasswordInfo] {

  def save(loginInfo: LoginInfo, authInfo: PasswordInfo): Future[PasswordInfo] = ???

  def find(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Option[PasswordInfo]] = ???
}

class OAuth1InfoDAO(implicit val classTag: ClassTag[OAuth1Info]) extends AuthInfoDAO[OAuth1Info] {

  def save(loginInfo: LoginInfo, authInfo: OAuth1Info): Future[OAuth1Info] = ???

  def find(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Option[OAuth1Info]] = ???
}
```

And last but not least the implementation of the service:

```
class DefaultAuthInfoService(info: AuthInfoDAO[AuthInfo]*) extends AuthInfoService {

  def save[T <: AuthInfo](loginInfo: LoginInfo, authInfo: T): Future[T] = {
    info.find(_.classTag.runtimeClass == authInfo.getClass) match {
      case Some(dao) => dao.save(loginInfo, authInfo).map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
      case _ => throw new Exception(SaveError.format(authInfo.getClass))
    }
  }

  def retrieve[T <: AuthInfo](loginInfo: LoginInfo)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Future[Option[T]] = {
    info.find(_.classTag == tag) match {
      case Some(dao) => dao.find(loginInfo).map(_.map(_.asInstanceOf[T]))
      case _ => throw new Exception(RetrieveError.format(tag.runtimeClass))
    }
  }
}
```

---

Now if I try to instantiate the service and pass the DAOs, the compiler says that trait `AuthInfoDAO` is invariant in type T. How can I solve this issue. I must admit that I did not really understand covariance and contravariance at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without variance headaches change following:

1. class DefaultAuthInfoService(info: AuthInfoDAO[_]*) extends AuthInfoService { ...
2. case Some(dao) => dao.asInstanceOf[AuthInfoDAO[T]].save(loginInfo, authInfo)

The DefaultAuthInfoService will look like this:

```
class DefaultAuthInfoService(info: AuthInfoDAO[_]*) extends AuthInfoService {

  def save[T <: AuthInfo](loginInfo: LoginInfo, authInfo: T): Future[T] = {
    info.find(_.classTag.runtimeClass == authInfo.getClass) match {
      case Some(dao) => dao.asInstanceOf[AuthInfoDAO[T]].save(loginInfo, authInfo)
      case _ => throw new Exception("a")
    }
  }

  def retrieve[T <: AuthInfo](loginInfo: LoginInfo)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Future[Option[T]] = {
    info.find(_.classTag == tag) match {
      case Some(dao) => dao.find(loginInfo).map(_.map(_.asInstanceOf[T]))
      case _ => throw new Exception("b")
    }
  }
}
```